# In radio button text is not aligned near it. its bit uplifted

Tags: html, css, radio-button

i am working on html radio buttons. in my code the radio buttons is placed. but the text near it is bit uplifted. please help me to align the text near it as the radio button as it usually is. http://jsfiddle.net/SFn6R/3/ . so when i fiddle it it works fine. but when i add it to my project . the text displays bit lifted from the radio button. any idea. thanks in advance

here is my code:

```
        .date {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
margin: 24px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: What do you call a 'bit lifted'. Is it the same on different browsers? I can't spot the lifted effect. But maybe adding a `vertical-align` property helps.

Comment: @PaulvdDool: its like the text is not in a straight line with the button. the button is less closer to the text.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure f this will work but you can try to

```
        .date {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
margin: 24px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
}
```

post your html like you did with with the older one

Answer (score 1):

put radio button and text in a table row it will work fine.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name=""></td>
<td>text you want to enter</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

try this if it does not work Reply. till then I can send you with some css code for doing this.

ok you can do this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><input type="radio" name=""></td>
<td valign="top">monday</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

try this and reply if it works or not

ok then i have seen your link i have done this it works fine for me. check it

```
<p class="date">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Date Range:</td> 


        <td><input type="radio" name="month" onchange="#" /></td><td>monday</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="month" onchange="#" /></td><td>tuesday</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="month" onchange="#" /></td><td>wednesday</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="month" onchange="#" /></td><td>thursday</td>
    </tr></table>
                        </p>
```

Comment: it reacts in the same way as the first solution.

Comment: also if you want your text to be aligned centre use **valign="top"** in your <td> where text is written

Comment: i really dont know what is the problem with my browser. it even didn't work. so is there any other way to achieve the same which i have in my fiddle?

Comment: i think you have some other problem other than coding please view all your codes properly may be you can find your error somewhere. becoz all above code is working fine for me.